The scope of the word ‘each’
I got a question from one of my students. In a sentence ‘Before we talk about each group’s event idea, I want you to understand the meaning of upcycling.’, he wondered only singular form of ‘idea’ can be used because of the word ‘each’ or the plural form ‘ideas’ can also be used in that sentence. I think both of them are fine in the sense of grammaticality and also acceptability. But I cannot think of any rightful theoretical backgrounds to explain the matter. Help me

This is not a question about linguistics, but about English grammar and usage, so it should probably be on [elu.se] or [ell.se]. But do you think the number of ideas should be limited by the word each? Ideas are not limited to one per person or group; if each group has three ideas, the singular would make no sense.

[Correction: that should have said, “But why do you think…?”.]

Like Janus said, "each group's leader" and "each group's members" are both perfectly valid (assuming a group has one leader and multiple members).
